# how to return all the resulted rows to other class function at one time in oop php?

Tags: php

> When I return this function on other page i gets only one result row
>   of array in object oriented php,help me & thanxx in advance.

```
  function select($query)
  {          
         // echo $query."<br>";  
         $this->slct_result= mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);       

         while($this->array_row = $this->slct_result->fetch_assoc())
         {             
            $this->get_cat= $this->array_row['cat_name'];       

            print_r($this->get_cat);
            return $this->get_cat;
         }
     }
```

Comment: put return out of while, and return a table of results gathered like `$results[] = $this->get_cat;` in while

Answer (score 0):

```
function select($query)
{          
    // echo $query."<br>";  
    $this->slct_result= mysqli_query($this->conn,$query); 
    $result = array();

    while($this->array_row = $this->slct_result->fetch_assoc())
    {             
        $this->get_cat= $this->array_row['cat_name'];       

        array_push($result, $this->get_cat);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

then, from whatever you're doing in other code:

```
$queryResult = select("QUERY");
foreach ($queryResult as $queryItem) {
    // doStuff($queryItem);
}
```